# Pandas Series Apply

Tags: pandas, apply

I want to create a new pandas series from an existing one based on a condition. I want to take each value in the series and compare it to an array of five values and take the nearest of those five values as the value for the new column at that index.

This is what I have currently:

```
nom_loads = array([-1089.32556032,  -873.46034816,  -657.595136  ,  -441.72992384,
    -225.86471168])

final_data['FZnom'] = final_data.FZ.apply(lambda x: nom_loads[np.argmax(x - nom_loads)])
```

But the column I get is simply 1089.3 i.e. nom_loads[0] in all the rows. In my understanding x in the lambda function should be each value of final_data.FZ row by row, but maybe that's incorrect on my part.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
lambda x: nom_loads[np.abs(x - nom_loads).argmin()]
```

inside `apply` because you are looking for **nearest** value, not **farthest** value. So `argmax` is not a correct choice.

You can use a broadcasting approach:

```
idx = np.abs(final_data.FZ.values[:,None] - nom_loads).argmin(-1)


final_data['FZnom'] = nom_loads[idx]
```